# Full file path is not showing in powershell Search command

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am trying to  search a multiple word in multiple  files in directories and saving the results in a text file using Powershell.
But what is happening is the paths are getting truncated if the paths are long.
So i need your help please

Here is the code:

```
$searchWords = 'black hat' ,'black'

Foreach ($sw in $searchWords)
{
    Get-Childitem -Path "D:\filesearchautomation\" -Recurse | 

    Select-String -Pattern "$sw" | 

    Select Path,LineNumber,@{n='SearchWord';e={$sw}} 

}
```

I saved this code as xxx.ps1 and run the command as below

```
cd D:\filesearchautomation\

.\xxx.ps1 > D:\results.txt
```

Comment: You could try something like `.\xxx.ps1 | Out-File D:\results.txt -Width 400` however I'd prefer `.\xxx.ps1 | Export-Csv D:\results.csv -NoTypeInformation`.

Comment: JosefZ  @, you are the Master. Your Trick works and  issue is Resolved. Thanks a ton and ton.